# Using sed to insert README.md in .gitignore

Tags: linux, sed

I'm attempting to use sed to insert `README.md` as the first line in the file `.gitignore`.  This is what I have:

```
ole@mki:~/test$ cat .gitignore 
line1
line2

ole@mki:~/test$ sed '1 i README.md' .gitignore
README.md
line1
line2
```

It prints the end result that I want, but does not actually insert README.md into `.gitignore`.

How do we get it to actually do the insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed -i '1 i README.md' .gitignore`

man sed:

```
   -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

          edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```